# How to get trusted timestamp value for a signed pkg in macOS?

Tags: c++, macos, security, digital-signature, pkgbuild

For a signed .app/binary we can get "signing-timestamp" (kSecCodeInfoTimestamp) using SecCodeCopySigningInformation method using SecStaticCodeRef in security framework.

But for pkg SecCode apis don't work & we need to fetch information using xar apis. Using `xar_signature_get_x509certificate_data` other information like issuer, serial no, validity time,etc is available but the signing time stamp, the time at which the pkg was signed is not available in the dictionary created by using `xar_signature_get_x509certificate_data` & `x509_st`. There is no api to get the trusted timestamp.

I tried running `pkgutil --check-signature` via code & parse it's output. For pkg with small size there is no issue. But if we have a huge file in GBs like the os upgrade InstallAssistant.pkg which is 12.2 GB, on terminal `pkgutil --check-signature` itself takes around 22sec to post the output.

How to get the timestamp, the value after `"Signed with a trusted timestamp on:"` for pkg programmatically?

e.x. pkgutil --check-signature zoomusInstallerFull.pkg

```
Status: signed by a developer certificate issued by Apple for distribution

Notarization: trusted by the Apple notary service

Signed with a trusted timestamp on: 2022-06-27 01:26:22 +0000

Certificate Chain:

    Developer ID Installer: Zoom Video Communications, Inc. (BJ4HAAB9B3) Expires: 2027-02-01 22:12:15 +0000 SHA256 Fingerprint: 6D 70 1A 84 F0 5A D4 C1 C1 B3 AE 01 C2 EF 1F 2E AE FB 9F 5C A6 80 48 A4 76 60 FF B5 F0 57 BB 8C ------------------------------------------------------------------------

    Developer ID Certification Authority Expires: 2027-02-01 22:12:15 +0000 SHA256 Fingerprint: 7A FC 9D 01 A6 2F 03 A2 DE 96 37 93 6D 4A FE 68 09 0D 2D E1 8D 03 F2 9C 88 CF B0 B1 BA 63 58 7F ------------------------------------------------------------------------

    Apple Root CA Expires: 2035-02-09 21:40:36 +0000 SHA256 Fingerprint: B0 B1 73 0E CB C7 FF 45 05 14 2C 49 F1 29 5E 6E DA 6B CA ED 7E 2C 68 C5 BE 91 B5 A1 10 01 F0 24
```

Comment: You might find [this](https://www.jamf.com/blog/reversing-pkgutil-to-verify-pkgs/) interesting

Comment: @TheNextman Had tried the PKArchive private framework code from https://github.com/objective-see/WhatsYourSign/blob/62f9e78d41e966cebeceec18fbfb2837625ff802/WhatsYourSignExt/FinderSync/Packages.m but it too validates the file & then gives the output. Validation takes time here too & output is delayed.